# Spring SAML cant read property from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

So this one stumps me.  I have been using properties files for years now, but I have never seen this.

I am using Spring MVC with SAML authentication.  my context xml has this in it:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/opt/saml.properties" />

<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="file:/opt/mySamlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${keystore.password}"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="${privateKey.alias}" value="${key.password}"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${privateKey.alias}"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

I so some SO research and they all say basically that I have the wrong password,  which im sure I don't.  So to test that it's reading the right file, I go and replace all the properties %{} and hard code them.  Everything then works fine.

I am trying to figure this out,  when I noticed that some of the other properties from that file are working!  In fact,  I can even do this:

```
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="file:/opt/myKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${keystore.password}"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="${privateKey.alias}" value="password"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${privateKey.alias}"/>
</bean>
```

So spring is getting ${keystore.password} and ${privateKey.alias} (Along with others needed like entityID, metadataProvider, etc...) from the properties file,  but not ${key.password} !!!

here is the saml.properties

```
#keystore stuff
keystore.password=password
key.password=password 
privateKey.alias=mysaml

#SP stuff   (aka,  my side of things)
entity.id=mycompany:me:me:me1
entity.base.url=https://mycompany.com

#IDP stuff   (aka, the SAML server)
metadata.provider=https://saml.mycompany.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
```

This is all working when I hard coded the key password,  but not when I use the ${key.password} property.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

you have two more slash after file

For example

```
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="file:///opt/myKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${keystore.password}"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="${privateKey.alias}" value="password"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${privateKey.alias}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Same error.  Spring is finding the file,  all the other properties are working, just not the key.password